# \begin{equation}: "Display math should end with $$" error?

Tags: math-mode, errors, equations

I'm pretty new to LaTeX, completely new actually, and there is one thing I can't quite understand.

I get the error "Display math should end with $$"
when writing an equation like this:

```
\begin{equation}

$R_{2}$=$\frac{U_{R_2}}{I_2}$=$\frac{2,95\, \mathrm{V}$}{$0,03*10^{-3}\, \mathrm{A}$} = 7,10\,\mathrm{k}\Omega \,.

\label{eq:Bsp_OhmsLaw}\end{equation}
```

I tried a lot of things, I also skimmed these forums. Nothing seemed to help :-(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site! You shouldn't use all of those `$` symbols within the `equation` environment; remove them, and the blank lines, and you should get closer to a working piece of code :)

Comment: Please post **complete** compilable code as this makes it much easier to understand and answer your question.

Comment: Also, $$ is from plain TeX and has been replaced in LaTeX with a host of options, including \\[ and \\].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to removing the `$` as cmhughes suggested, the blank lines in the `equation` environment confuse things. This may be why you added the dollar signs - with the blanks, LaTeX otherwise complains about missing `$` symbols in the code.

Here's a working version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  R_{2}=\frac{U_{R_2}}{I_2}=\frac{2,95\, \mathrm{V}}{0,03*10^{-3}\, \mathrm{A}} = 7,10\,\mathrm{k}\Omega \,.
  \label{eq:Bsp_OhmsLaw}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: equation]

Comment: Thank's so much!
It may sound odd, but my professor never really expained why and how to properly use the $ signs, so I just use them before and after every term that isn't just text.. worked fine so far, but I can see it leads to the first problems already.

Comment: Bascially, `equation` already tells TeX it is in maths mode. That's why you need e.g. `\mathrm{}` to get something text-like. If you are in a maths environment like that, don't use `$` signs. Normally, you'd use `$` signs if you wanted to typeset some maths inline i.e. in the middle of a paragraph or in the cell of a table or something like that.

Comment: @cfr Or, even better than `$...$`, you can use `\(...\)`.

Comment: You could also change * to \times to get a properly typeset multiplication symbol, and even though it is obvious from context in this case, * is used for other operations in mathematics.

Comment: I'd also like to mention that it's generally a good idea to not use several equals signs in the same line.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package for typesetting physical quantities:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE % comma as decimal mark
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Bsp_OhmsLaw}
  R_{2}
  = \frac{U_{2}}{I_{2}}
  = \frac{\SI{2.95}{\volt}}{\SI{0.03e-3}{\ampere}}
  = \SI{7.10}{\kilo\ohm}.
\end{equation}
Ohm's law is used in equation~\eqref{eq:Bsp_OhmsLaw}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) has given [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168400/15874) to why the initial code isn't compiling.

**Update**

You can make the code a bit shorter by use abbreviations for the physical units:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE % comma as decimal mark
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Bsp_OhmsLaw}
  R_{2}
  = \frac{U_{2}}{I_{2}}
  = \frac{\SI{2.95}{\V}}{\SI{0.03e-3}{\A}}
  = \SI{7.10}{\kohm}.
\end{equation}
Ohm's law is used in equation~\eqref{eq:Bsp_OhmsLaw}.

\end{document}
```

(See [page 37 of the manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf#page=37).)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more instructive to write out `\V` and `\A` as it was done with `\kiko\ohm`. Also unless really really required to, I'd recommend using `.` as the decimal point, not comma. Otherwise one will have to wrap all non unit numbers in `\num{...}` which is a big hassle if one have not done so from the beginning.

Comment: @daleif Regarding `\V` and `\A`: I guess. (The reverse case: Do you know if there is an abbreviation for `\kiko\ohm`?) The comma is because that is how it is in the question.

Comment: `abreviations` `\kohm`

Comment: @daleif You could also use the `icomma` package to get properly spacing if comma is used a decimal separator.

Comment: In that case I'd rather use the `siunitx` approach and not have globally active math comma