# How can I write this equation with LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, equations, environments, indexing, delimiters

I am new here. I would like to type an equation with LaTeX but I could not produce what I want so far..

I tried this example:

`m[\dot{u} - vr + wq -$x_{G}$(q^2+r^2) + $y_{G}$(pq - \dot{r}) + $z_{G}$(pr + \dot{r})] = \(\Sigma\)$X_{ext}$`

But then I have got an error like this:

`! Display math should end with $$. <to be read again>  x l.100 m[\dot{u} - vr + wq -$x _{G}$(q^2+r^2) + $y_{G}$(pq - \dot{r}) + $z_{G}...`

Below given image is actually what I want to express with LaTeX. Anyone can help?

[image]

Comment: You should probably start by reading a basic introduction to latex. You want the entire thing in math mode (`\dot` does not work outside math), thus you want `$....$` around the entire thing, not just bits of it.

Comment: You keep entering and leaving math mode (with all of the `$`). For a display equation try `\[m[\dot{u} - vr + wq -x_{G}(q^2+r^2) + y_{G}(pq - \dot{r}) + z_{G}(pr + \dot{r})] = \Sigma X_{ext}\]` or for inline replace `\[` and `\]`  with `\(` and `\)`. Your making a similar mistake to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168398/beginequation-display-math-should-end-with-error?rq=1) so have look at the answers there.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Please, consider comments below question and make yourself more familiar with LaTeX. For start may be good to read [The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX 2ε](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf)
and the following rewriting of your equation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
m[\dot{u} - vr + wq -x_{G}(q^2+r^2) + y_{G}(pq - \dot{r}) + z_{G}(pr + \dot{r})] = \sum X_{\mathrm{ext}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @daleif, you are right. Corrected now.